# Go lang access denied

Tags: windows, go, file-access

I'm new to the GO programming language, what I'm trying to do is to put some items into the map and then remove one of them, when I'm trying to remove one of the items from array I'm getting the error message:

```
C:/Go\bin\go.exe run C:/Users/Computer/IdeaProjects/untitled1/simple.go
fork/exec C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build143466426\command-line-arguments\_obj\exe\simple.exe: Access is denied.
```

the code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

    func main(){
    
        presAge := make(map[string] int)
    
        presAge["test"] = 42
        presAge["boom"] = 421
    
        delete(presAge,"boom")
    
        fmt.Println(len(presAge))
    
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/issues/153

Comment: As others have pointed out you can add exclusion in your anti virus, but this solotion dosent sit well with me. So after some searching I found that using GoLand (Jet Brains) you can just run the application using the built in runner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the trick here is that you need to run your application as Administrator in Windows

Comment: Sounds wrong to me

Comment: Still get the error actually (at least in my case)

Answer (score 14):

I can only speak for my own case. I ran into the similar error using Windows 10. After some experiments, it looks like the error came from Avira, the anti-virus software I was using. Basically, the .exe file is detected by Avira as containing the pattern of a type of virus (called HEUR/APC (Cloud) in my case), which prevents the program from executing.

After I disabled my anti-virus software, everything went back to normal.

Comment: it helped me too.

Answer (score 7):

for me I used avira just add `C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Local\Temp` floder to exception folder for realtime-protection.

Solved my problem

Comment: Rather than excluding the entire Local folder, a safer solution is to set the environment variable GOTMPDIR to a directory, then exclude only that directory from malware scanners.

Answer (score 3):

**** Only Applies if you have avira antivirus installed on your pc ****

The thing is that avira recognises the go interpreter similar to a certain virus(HEUR/APC).
So it blocks it and we get this error.

[see the first row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hF60y.png)

Just go to settings in the same page and add a exception to a folder like i have done so.

[add this path to the exception : **C:\Users\User\AppData\Local**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n35VL.png)

Then press Ok and apply and you'll be good to go.

P.S. - I see that someone else also pointed out that it's the avira antivirus but didn't give proper solution to the problem, so i thought to give a proper solution from my side.

Comment: Rather than excluding the entire Local folder, a safer solution is to set the environment variable GOTMPDIR to a directory, then exclude only that directory from malware scanners.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct.
You can run it via https://play.golang.org/ and it will print "1"

The error you're getting is not a Go error but a Windows error.
It looks like a permission problem (no idea why you're getting it)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me as I had no admin rights to deactivate my antivirus

go build main.exe; main./exe

Comment: Instead of disabling antivirus or antimalware, the other answers posted here to exclude a single folder are a safer solution.

Answer (score 0):

Adding code folder to the exception list solved the problem

**Windows Security-> Virus and Threat Protection Settings -> Exclutions->Add folder**

Add your **workplace folder** here where your code exists. Adding temp folder didn't work for me.

```
go build gotest.go ; .\gotest.exe
```

Using the above command (regular command prompt.) can eliminate pop-up alerts but don't know the reason.

Answer (score -1):

I am getting the same error  and its because of my Cylance Protect antivirus. Try disabling it.

Comment: Instead of disabling antivirus or antimalware, the other answers posted here to exclude a single folder are a safer solution.

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me too, but it's not a Go problem, it's a Windows problem.  I didn't have any antivirus going on, so what I did was that if I was going to work with Go, (whatever the text editor) I run it as admin. That solved my problem (WINDOWS only)