# Golang showing access denied error on "go run"

Tags: go

I have installed Go today and have set up the Hello World code according to their documentation, but whenever I do "go run ." it throws following error

```
go tool compile: fork/exec C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64\compile.exe: Access denied.
```

Here is output of "go env"

```
set GO111MODULE=
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\a\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOEXPERIMENT=
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\Users\a\go\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\a\go
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=C:\Program Files\Go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GOVCS=
set GOVERSION=go1.17.2
set GCCGO=gccgo
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=C:\Users\a\hello\go.mod
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build1135035406=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

I have installed Go in C:\Program Files\Go, I also tried reinstalling once.
I am on Windows 10.

"go version" outputs this `go version go1.17.2 windows/amd64`

Comment: Try to run cmd/power shell with admin rights

Comment: When you say "their documentation", do you mean https://golang.org/doc/install ?

Comment: I followed ^ that on my windows 10 box just now, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I've tried running in Powershell and cmd with admin rights and no difference.
And yes I've installed according to this https://golang.org/doc/install

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/43019581/10197418

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Go lang access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019581/go-lang-access-denied)

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with my Goland IDE.
i tried to run the main .go and got the error in the output.

I solved it by running it one more time.
Edit: Use command `go run main.go` 3-4 times.

Comment: Please try to not use images and instead paste the terminal text into your answer and use code blocks to format them.