# Getting access denied error after running Terraform init cmd

Tags: azure, terraform

while running Terraform validate getting below error:-

```
fork/exec .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm/3.14.0/windows_amd64/terraform-provider-azurerm_v3.14.0_x5.exe: Access is denied.
```

When running Terraform Plan getting below error:-

```
│ Error: Failed to load plugin schemas
│
│ Error while loading schemas for plugin components: Failed to obtain provider schema: Could not load the schema for provider
│ registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm: failed to instantiate provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm" to obtain schema: fork/exec
│ .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm/3.14.0/windows_amd64/terraform-provider-azurerm_v3.14.0_x5.exe: Access is denied...
```

Note:

1. I have tried with deleting lock file and .terraform  and rerun terraform init same error getting.
2. Given all(full permission) access to user on required folder.
3. Checked with older version and newer version of azurerm provided but getting same error still.

please  check and let me know possible solution.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeM3K.png)

Comment: Please do not post screenshots. Code blocks are much more useful for debugging purposes.

Comment: Also, have you added the location of the terraform binary to your PATH variable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43019581/1032785

Comment: Other users report this happening due to local antivirus, see question above.

Answer (score 2):

1- Remove .terraform from your local data.
2- commit the changes to remove those from the git as well.
3- include .terraform on your git ignore, terraform will download those on runtime.
4- run terraform init to make your local env work again.
5- profit

At least for me, those steps fixed the same problem I was having with the azurerm provider.

Comment: Hello All, Thanks for the valuable input. it was blocking because of local antivirus. now i have added file into exclusion list. now its working fine. Thanks @ 
Marko E ,  jordanm

Answer (score 0):

I was getting access denied error after running terraform init and terraform init -reconfigure multiple times but was still getting access denied error.

You also need to check the bucket names in the provider section. I had this issue as i copied the code from other projects.