# GoLang command-line-arguments:

Tags: go, concurrency, goland

I am new to go language. When I use GoLand to compile my code, it prompts an error message: `command-line-arguments: open C:\Users\Young\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build2051388383\b001\exe\a.out.exe: Access is denied.`
And this is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "regexp"
)

var (
    reQQEmail = `(\d+)@qq.com`
)

func GetEmail() {
    
    resp, err := http.Get("https://tieba.baidu.com/p/6051076813?red_tag=1573533731")
    HandleError(err, "http.Get url")
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    pageBytes, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    HandleError(err, "io.ReadAll")

    pageStr := string(pageBytes)
    // fmt.Println(pageStr)

    re := regexp.MustCompile(reQQEmail)
    results := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(pageStr, -1)

    for _, info := range results {
        fmt.Println("email:", info[0])
        fmt.Println("qq:", info[1])
    }
}

func HandleError(err error, msg string) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(msg, err)
    }
}

func main() {
    GetEmail()
}
```

I asked chatgpt and it provided a lot of possible reasons, but I couldn't figure out where to start.

Comment: CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied.

Comment: Looks like antivirus software intervention.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Go lang access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019581/go-lang-access-denied)